# Get normalized coordinates of touch gesture with origin as centre

Tags: android

I have a linear layout that I have assigned an `onTouchListener`. I have gotten the width and height of the device but the problem is, the origin is at the top left of the screen and it's giving me coordinates like (534, 211) for example.

I would like the origin to be at the center of the screen and I would like the very ends of the screen coordinates to be 1.

How can I implement this?

This is the code I got so far...

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        System.out.println(width + " " + height);

        mGLView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getX() + " " + event.getY());
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Here is an image showing the kind of coordinate system I am trying to implement:
[image]

Comment: So you want the x and y-axis to go from -1,1 where 0,0 is the screen center?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly right. If you want, I can post an image using MS Paint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get get the coordinates (`getX()` and `getY()`) from the `MotionEvent` and normalize them into the coordinates you want. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = 2f * (event.getX() / v.getWidth()) - 1f;
    float y = -2f * (event.getY() / v.getHeight()) + 1f;

    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    return false;
}
```

(This assumes that you want your coordinate system relative to the view itself -- in your code you also query the *display's* dimensions, but I'm not sure why).

Comment: Haha, yeah that was stupid. I thought because my view is the whole screen I can just take the screen dimensions. Anyway, your solution works nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can map a point from any range to any range using the following function:

For your case: toRange is (-1,1) and fromRange is (0,width) and (0,height)

```
double map(double input,double toMin, double toMax,
                                      double fromMin, double fromMax){

   return ((input - fromMin)/(fromMax - fromMin)) * (toMax - toMin) +toMin
}
```

You can then using it as follows:

```
map(250,-1,1,0,screenWidth)
map(300,-1,1,0,screenHeight)
```

You can build on top of this function whatever mapping you wish, for example

```
double center(double input, double maxValue) {
  return map(input,-1,1,0,maxValue);
}
```

Then use it in your code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  System.out.println(center(event.getX(),v.getWidth()) +
                               " " + center(event.getY(),v.getHeight()));
  return false;
}
```